# how I do a select dynamic with the contents of the template / layout using cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have to create a select to receive all the content within the folder "src / Template / Layout", someone could help me with this task? I can not imagine how to do this!

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking. Also you should provide yuer efforts. See the [**help center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask

Answer (score 0):

if you need to select all available layouts `'.ctp files'` under src/Template/Layout foleder?

Then have a look at `Files and Folders` section of CakePHP under

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html